# mLACP / MC-LAG between Cisco / Juniper

Tags: cisco, juniper, juniper-junos, vpls, ldp

I am working on a LDP signalled VPLS topology (picture)

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish here is to establish a redundant connection to CE1.
CE1 has both interfaces in a port-channel with an IP.

My PE1 device is a CSR1000v and PE2 is a Juniper vMX.

My VPLS core is operating OK, connectivity between CE2 and CE3 is established (all CEs are the same customer)

I am trying to bundle CE1-facing interfaces in a mLACP so what link with PE1 is primary and link with PE2 is backup but I have failed every attempt and somehow am unable to find a working solution (i was only able to achieve this state using a uPE device and H-VPLS, i am now trying to eliminate using the additional machine).

I would be thankful for any advice, since i am new to VPLS.

PE1 VPLS:

```
l2 vfi VPLS manual
 vpn id 100
 bridge-domain 1
 neighbor 10.255.255.2 encapsulation mpls --- PE2
 neighbor 10.255.255.3 encapsulation mpls --- PE3
```

PE2 VPLS:

```
routing-instances {
VPLS {
    instance-type vpls;
    interface ge-0/0/1.0; --- to CE2
    protocols {
        vpls {
            no-tunnel-services;
            vpls-id 100;
            neighbor 10.255.255.1 { --- PE1
                encapsulation-type ethernet;
            }
            neighbor 10.255.255.3 { --- PE3
                encapsulation-type ethernet;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Multichassis LACP is vendor specific. I don't see how this could be made to work the way you've described it. (CE1 can't for a LAG with two vendor's LACP engines.) Maybe Shortest Path Bridging (SPB  / 802.1aq) is an option. Otherwise, the ages old VRRP is all I can recommend.

Comment: `mLACP so what link with PE1 is primary and link with PE2 is backup`.  The "primary/backup" concept does not fit with LACP - this would be against the basic idea of LACP: all (active) links in an aggregate are meant to be equal, and the given LACP speaking device may distribute/load-share the to-be-sent frames over all active links.

Comment: The config snippets in your question (currently) show no details about the CE1 facing interfaces. Please add them, too.